# Google closure compiler ADVANCED mode breaks code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

I'm compiled this example `javascript` code with **Google Closure Compiler**

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
   console.log('Hello');
});
```

And, I got this output from that.

```
$(document).a("click",function(){console.log("Hello")});
```

Here `on` replaced with `a`. So, when I run this on browser I got error.

I'm used this command line for compiling script.

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js script.js
```

When I'm using `--process_jquery_primitives` argument I got this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptionsPreprocessor$InvalidOptionsException: The jQuery pass and the Closure pass cannot both be enabled.
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerExecutor.runInCompilerThread(CompilerExecutor.java:126)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.runInCompilerThread(Compiler.java:740)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:710)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:680)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.AbstractCommandLineRunner.doRun(AbstractCommandLineRunner.java:1080)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.AbstractCommandLineRunner.run(AbstractCommandLineRunner.java:492)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.main(CommandLineRunner.java:1866)
Caused by: com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptionsPreprocessor$InvalidOptionsException: The jQuery pass and the Closure pass cannot both be enabled.
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptionsPreprocessor.preprocess(CompilerOptionsPreprocessor.java:74)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.compileInternal(Compiler.java:746)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.access$000(Compiler.java:84)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler$2.call(Compiler.java:713)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler$2.call(Compiler.java:710)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerExecutor$2.call(CompilerExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Note:** I'm using latest closure compiler

Comment: Not all code is safe for `ADVANCED` mode compilation. See http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html

Answer (score 3):

The reason the output changed is because with the compilation level set to `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, the Closure Compiler will rename all functions and variables to the simplest form.

There are function and variable names it is configured to avoid renaming like `console.log` and property names like `height`, `width` etc. By default it doesn't understand that jQuery functions shouldn't be renamed, so when it comes across them they will be changed.

There two ways of getting around this:

1. Create a jQuery externs file and pass it to the compiler. An externs
   file is a file containing function and variable definitions that help the compiler to recognize that it should not rename anything matching the definition provided.
2. Use square bracket notation instead of dot notation to access jQuery functions and variables. Using this method, the square bracket will be converted into a dot notation, but without renaming the variable.

Using your code

```
$(document)['on']('click', function () {
   console.log('Hello');
});
```

will be compiled to

```
$(document).on("click",function(){console.log("Hello")});
```

To extend this example, when you have an object with properties you don't want to be changed, use quotes around them when you declare the object eg

Instead of

```
var foo = {bar:'bar'};
```

Use

```
var foo = {'bar':'bar'};
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Well maintained jQuery externs are part of the compiler project (and distributed through npm). See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `--process_jquery_primitives`. From [the docs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/jQuery-Expansions):

> jQuery uses conventions that Closure Compiler doesn’t natively
>   understand. In order to produce functioning code, remove warnings and
>   enable optimizations, Closure Compiler expands known jQuery methods
>   and aliases in a similar way to how macros are expanded in other
>   languages.

Comment: I got this error when I'm using that argument on command line.